# SQL Server Reporting Services Basics

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

This project I'm working on has me using SQL Server 2008 R2 which I'm pretty new to.  I have the full version of SQL Server and, SSIS, SSAS etc.  What I don't know anything about is reporting services.  I can connect to the report server but I don't see anyway to actually build reports.  This is all in management studio, by the way.  Is there a GUI interface for building reports?  I have to assume that this software is distinct from SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio). It's in your SQL Server setup. Maybe you already did, have a look in your Visual Studio directory in your start menu.

Comment: There is no 'Business Intelligence' icon, but I do remember working on this computer before and there being one for SQL Server 2005.  Was BIDS always a part of SQL Server 2008?  I wasn't the person who installed the software on this machine; is it possible to install SQL Server and NOT install BIDS?

Comment: I don't know if it always, but at least since SQL Server 2005 or even 2000. And it is possible to install SQL Server and NOT BIDS.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible to install that way.

Business Intelligence Development Studio is a must to USE SSIS feature.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I might have to re-install SQL Server